# Python len function does not work on dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have this code:

```
ab = {  'Swaroop'   :   'swaroop@swaroopch.com',
            'Larry'        :    'larry@wall.org',
            'Matsumoto' :   'matz@ruby-lang.org',
            'Spammer'   :   'spammer@hotmail.com'
        }

print "Swaroop's address is", ab['Swaroop']

del ab['Spammer']

print '\nThere are {} contacts in the address-book\n'.format(len(ab))

for name, address in ab.items():
    print 'Contact {} at {}'.format(name, address)

ab['Guido'] = 'guido@python.org'

if 'Guido' in ab:
    print "\nGuido's address is", ab['Guido']
```

and i am getting this error in the GUI:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python26/cook.py", line 11, in <module>
    print '\nThere are {} contacts in the address-book\n'.format(len(ab))
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Why is this happening since the len(ab) = 3?

How can I have `zero length field name in format` ?

Comment: I am not aware of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.6, you need to specify the index, for which the data corresponds to, explicitly, like this

```
print '\nThere are {0} contacts in the address-book\n'.format(len(ab))
```

Comment: It is supposed to take 3 as value. The length of the dictionary.

Comment: Wow strange!!! It gives out 3 in the GUI! Could you please tell me why? I have learnt that i always should let {} blank!

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant The `{0}`, corresponds to the index of the items passed as parameters to `format`. In this case, you are telling that `len(ab)` has to be substituted instead of `{0}`.

Comment: Wow holly moses since I have one argument in format i Should put 0. I understand now. That guy in Byte of Python (http://swaroopch.com/book/python/#data_structures) tutorial just lives it blank(12.4 Dictionary)!

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant In Python 2.7, by default it fills the numbers in it :) So, we don't have to explicitly mention them. It was not available in Python 2.6

Comment: You are great!!! Thank you! I made a duplicate by mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant That is okay :) Duplicate questions help people to reach the actual answer, even though they use different keywords to search. So, I would say, your question serves a good purpose here :)